# Date validation across timezones

Tags: javascript, ajax, date, timezone

This may sound trivial. Here's what I want.

I'm had a database field called Date of Assessment, which should not be greater than today's date. I'm performing the validation in the html page and then sending the date as a JSON string to a ASP.Net application to save. This server application may reside in a different timezone.

I obviously have to perform the date validation again on the server. If a user is specifying a date in say Japan as 20th June 2009. The HTML validation will pass. However when it reaches the server in the US where the date is still 19th June 2009, it will fail.

The similar validation for date of birth. It should validate that the date is at least 18 years old. But when displaying on the web, it should always show the same date regardless of where the user is seeing it. The date of birth may be 18 years old in Japan but not in the server. It should still store, but when it displays the correct date should be displayed.

This is not a problem with datetime cos I will be using UTC times in this case.

Any ideas on how to validate, save and display the correct date?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use getTimezoneOffset() to first get the timezone in client, and send the value back as a param. Your server side can then calculate with this timezone offset.

```
var d = new Date();
alert(d.getTimezoneOffset());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save timestamp at backend and validate your date against local timezone at frontend. This works well in scenario where you deals with various timezones.